# C# WPF | Is There A Way To Play UHD Video In MediaElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I recently trying to play a video in 4k (3840x2160) that i've downloaded from YouTube in a Media Element. But problem, nothing appears !!

The same video with the same codec in HD (1920x1080) play perfectly !!

Is there a way to play the video in 4k ? (I tried some nuget packages but it doesn't work either)

PS: Media Element is not obliged !

**Code :**

```
<Window x:Class="VideoPlay.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VideoPlay"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Background="#181818" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement Height="800" Width="Auto" Stretch="Uniform" Source="C:\Users\Utilisateur\Downloads\COSTA RICA 4K HDR 60FPS.webm" LoadedBehavior="Play"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Did you try FFME?

Comment: @Byrd No, not yet do you think it would work ?

Comment: I'm not sure I haven't worked with FFME, but I do remember that some screen capture software I used uses FFmpeg. Chrome, and VLC use it too. FFME seems to use it for its WPF control alternative.

Comment: @Byrd I'm currently trying to play a video with FFME, i'll tell you if it's working ! :)